# input multiple .txt files in Perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have an online Perl concordance that searches for a target word in a particular text file and prints the sorted output. The test code presently searches for the keyword only in a single text file and prints the output. But I would like to do the same for all the text files present in the folder and not only a single text file. Any suggestion regarding this would be very helpful.!

Here is the code for my online Concordance:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

# require
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use CGI;

# sanity check
my $q = new CGI;
my $target = $q->param("keyword");
my $radius = $q->param("span");
my $ordinal = $q->param("ord");
my $width = 2*$radius;
my $file    = 'DISS.G.HB.002.txt';
if ( ! $file or ! $target ) {

    print "Usage: $0 <file> <target>\n";
    exit;

}

# initialize
my $count   = 0;
my @lines   = ();
$/          = ""; # Paragraph read mode

# open the file, and process each line in it
open(FILE, " < $file") or die("Can not open $file ($!).\n");
while(<FILE>){

    # re-initialize
    my $extract = '';

    # normalize the data
    chomp;
    s/\n/ /g;        # Replace new lines with spaces
    s/\b--\b/ -- /g; # Add spaces around dashes

    # process each item if the target is found
    while ( $_ =~ /\b$target\w*/gi ){

        # find start position
        my $match = $1;
        my $pos   = pos;
        my $start = $pos - $radius - length($match);

        # extract the snippets
        if ($start < 0){
            $extract = substr($_, 0, $width+$start+length($match));
            $extract = (" " x -$start) . $extract;
        }else{
            $extract = substr($_, $start, $width+length($match));
            my $deficit = $width+length($match) - length($extract);
            if ($deficit > 0) {
                $extract .= (" " x $deficit);
            }

        }

        # add the extracted text to the list of lines, and increment
        $lines[$count] = $extract;
        ++$count;

    }

}

sub removePunctuation {
    my $string = $_[0];
    $string = lc($string); # Convert to lowercase
    $string =~ s/[^-a-z ]//g; # Remove non-aplhabetic characters 
    $string =~ s/--+/ /g; #Remove 2+ hyphens with a space 
    $string =~s/-//g; # Remove hyphens
    $string =~ s/\s=/ /g;
    return($string);

}

sub onLeft {
    #USAGE: $word = onLeft($string, $radius, $ordinal);
    my $left = substr($_[0], 0, $_[1]);
    $left = removePunctuation($left);
    my @word = split(/\s+/, $left);
    return($word[-$_[2]]);
}

sub byLeftWords {
    my $left_a = onLeft($a, $radius, $ordinal);
    my $left_b = onLeft($b, $radius, $ordinal);
    lc($left_a) cmp lc($left_b);
}


# process each line in the list of lines

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
my $line_number = 0;

foreach my $x (sort byLeftWords @lines){
    ++$line_number;
    printf "%5d",$line_number;
    print " $x\n\n";
}

# done
exit;
```

Comment: See alos [Lingua::Concordance](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Concordance)

Comment: So... you've written 100+ lines of code---which you've dumped here in its entirety---but you couldn't even make an attempt at using something like [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) or [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) to scan a directory?

Comment: @Matt, your answer is not helpful either. Deep Shah has had trouble enough a month and a half ago, trying to get his CGI working, and gets stuck again. That is where his massive code dump has come from. Hopefully your `readdir` suggestion might get some progress... but @Matt can do better than that - grtzzz

Comment: Before you do anything else you should go and accept an answer to each of your previous questions that has been resolved.

Comment: @vanHoesel I didn't provide an answer! And I won't provide an answer to a question that shows no research effort or attempt to solve the problem. As it's currently written, this is not a good question for SO.

Comment: @MattJacob I am totally new to Perl and in fact this is actually my first Perl script so am still learning how to do things in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob()` function will return a list of files which match a pattern.

```
my @text_files = glob('*.txt');
```

Of course, you probably don't need the intermediate `@text_files` variable.

```
while (my $file = glob('*.txt')) {
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
  # do something with the filehandle
}
```

Some other suggestions for your code.

- `-w` was largely replaced with `use warnings` when Perl 5.6 was released in 2000.
- `new CGI` is far better written as `CGI->new`.
- Changes to special variables (like `$/`) should always be localised.
- Please use lexical filehandles and the three-arg version of `open()` (as demonstrated in my example above).
- If you're using CGI.pm, then why not use its `header()` method as well?

But, most importantly, please reconsider your use of CGI. Please read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for some better (by which I mean simpler and more powerful) suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help